# Setting up cakephp on Amazon EC2

Tags: cakephp, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to setup cakephp on an Amazon EC2 (Ubuntu) instance ..
however when i try running the code .. it shows no color, no
styles, no layout etc. 
I have updated the httpd.conf with the following content ..

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All

It still doesnt seem to work.

What is it that am doing wrong ???

Regards
Abhishek Jain

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Found out that my .htaccess files didn't have the permission to override anything, because AllowOverride was set to none.

I looked for the value in my `httpd.conf` file under `/etc/httpd/conf/` and changed it to `All`

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not EC2 related but I had a simmilar issue on the Mac when installing CakePHP on Mamp. A complete delete of all the CakePHP files and a re-install solved the issue for me.

Comment: Might be helpfull, http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/BBBThunda/2010/02/25/troubleshooting-cakephp-installation-issues-related-to-apache-2-mod_rewrite-for-beginners

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much too much experience installing Cake, but you should probably check the following anyway:

a) Do you have the correct .htaccess files in the correct directories? Linux treats anything that starts with '.' as a system file, so you have to do

```
ls -a
```

to check if they are present. If you moved the files into the directories manually, instead of unpacking the Cake download in the location you wanted it, the .htaccess files may not have been moved.

b) Check your Apache error logs (I assume you're using apache) for errors, especially errors loading mod_rewrite. Make sure LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/httpd/mod_rewrite.so and AddModule mod_rewrite.c are specified in httpd.conf.

c) Where did you put this?

> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride All

Without seeing more of your httpd.conf, there's no way of telling whether the Cake document root is inheriting these settings correctly.